# ubuntu as router, 2 nics, 2 lans, outside lan can not connect to inside lan

Tags: router, ping

How can I make LAN on `192.168.1.xxx` (`eth2`) forward packets to other LAN (`eth0`) `10.42.0.19` (Win7 PC)?

Both the LANs are connected to Ubuntu PC. I can ping from PC connected to `eth0` to PC connected to `eth2`. However, I can not ping from PC connected to `eth2` to PC connected to `eth0`.

You can see `tracert` can complete on way but not other way. How to make that work?

This way from second Win7 works to first Win7:

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 192.168.200.36

Tracing route to WIN7 [192.168.200.36]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  wr850g.hr.cox.net [192.168.1.1]
  3    25 ms    24 ms    31 ms  WIN7 [192.168.1.100]
  4    18 ms    17 ms    40 ms  WIN7 [192.168.200.36]

Trace complete.
```

This way from first Win7 to second Win7 is broken:

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 10.42.0.19

Tracing route to 10.42.0.19 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    52 ms     1 ms     1 ms  hubrouter.westell.com [192.168.200.1]
  2    43 ms    98 ms    45 ms  192.168.1.1
  3    45 ms   105 ms    24 ms  SCOTT-PC [192.168.1.102]
  4  SCOTT-PC [192.168.1.102]  reports: Destination protocol unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

From first Win7 to Ubuntu router works:

```
C:\Users\scott>tracert 10.42.0.1

Tracing route to SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1   105 ms    <1 ms     4 ms  hubrouter.westell.com [192.168.200.1]
  2    19 ms    17 ms    33 ms  192.168.1.1
  3    35 ms    34 ms     5 ms  SCOTT-P5QC [10.42.0.1]

Trace complete.
```

`netstat` routes in Ubuntu router:

```
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         wr850g.hr.cox.n 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth2
10.42.0.0       *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth2
```

Hand copy of LAN layout:

[image: Hand copy of LAN layout]

I have also posted this question at [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102810)

Answer (score 2):

Solved by installing `webmin`. Then used it to reset `iptables`. Seriously, a great tool for administering the firewall.

`webmin` told me 2 rules were in the `iptables` which it could not understand, so I save `iprules` to a file, did a reset and all the 3 PCs can share files.

A defacto firewall is running all the time using `iptables`. So they must be modified.

```
scott@scott-P5QC:~$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.580_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package webmin.
(Reading database ... 229686 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking webmin (from webmin_1.580_all.deb) ...
Setting up webmin (1.580) ...
Webmin install complete. You can now login to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo
to run commands as root.
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
```

To show what it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

---

Source - [Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-server.html)